# Spring Integration - Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am trying to build a small application using Spring Integration Framework. I am facing some exception while calling a post request.
Below is my code and exception i am getting. I am able to insert the data with this exception.

Exception

```
2018-12-03 23:58:55.659 ERROR 15180 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.resPostMedChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=5, headers={content-length=65, http_requestMethod=POST, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@9135598, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9, http_statusCode=200 OK, accept=*/*, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@9135598, host=localhost:8080, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8080/medicine, connection=keep-alive, id=b09085f5-7b54-061d-fe1a-f4e98b9de021, cache-control=no-cache, contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36, timestamp=1543861735642}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=5, headers={content-length=65, http_requestMethod=POST, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@9135598, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9, http_statusCode=200 OK, accept=*/*, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@9135598, host=localhost:8080, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8080/medicine, connection=keep-alive, id=b09085f5-7b54-061d-fe1a-f4e98b9de021, cache-control=no-cache, contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36, timestamp=1543861735642}]] with root cause

org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:451) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:400) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:415) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:334) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:225) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:451) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:400) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:183) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:451) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:503) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:470) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:357) ~[spring-integration-http-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:256) ~[spring-integration-http-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:108) ~[spring-integration-http-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Models Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="medicine")
public class Medicine {
@Id
@Column(name="med_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int medId;

@Column(name="med_name")
private String medName;

@Column(name="exp_date")
private String expDate;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="Dose_Medicine", joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="med_Id")}, 
inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="dose_Id")})
@JsonIgnore
private List<Dose> doses = new ArrayList<Dose>();

//setter getter
}
```

Dose Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dose")
public class Dose {
@Id
@Column(name="dose_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int doseId;

@Column(name="dose_value")
private String doseValue;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, 
mappedBy="doses")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Medicine> medicine = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
//setter getter
}
```

Service Activator

```
@Component
public class MedicineServiceActivator {
@Autowired
private MedicineService medicineService;
    public MessageBuilder<?> saveMedicine(Message<Medicine> msg) {
    return 
MessageBuilder.withPayload(medicineService.saveMedicine(msg.getPayload()))

.copyHeadersIfAbsent(msg.getHeaders()).setHeader("http_statusCode", 
HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class MedicineService {

@Autowired
private MediceneRepository medicineRepo;
public int saveMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
    medicineRepo.save(medicine);
    return medicine.getMedId();
}
}
```

Repository

```
public interface MediceneRepository extends CrudRepository<Medicine, 
Integer> {
}
```

Integration XML

```
<int:channel id="reqPutMedChannel" />
<int:channel id="resPutMedChannel" />
<int:channel id="reqPostMedChannel" />
<int:channel id="resPostMedChannel" />
<int:channel id="routeMedRequest" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway
    request-channel="routeMedRequest" 
    supported-methods="POST, PUT" path="/medicine"
    request-payload-type="com.cerner.api.Model.Medicine">

    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" 
produces="application/json"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:router input-channel="routeMedRequest" 
expression="headers.http_requestMethod">
    <int:mapping value="PUT" channel="reqPutMedChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="POST" channel="reqPostMedChannel" />
</int:router>

<int:service-activator ref="medicineServiceActivator" 
method="updateMedicine" 
    input-channel="reqPutMedChannel" output-channel="resPutMedChannel"/>
<int:service-activator ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="saveMedicine" 
    input-channel="reqPostMedChannel" output-channel="resPostMedChannel"/>
```

One more help. If i have to make a POST request what should be the JSON.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You are missing to share a configuration exactly for the `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.resPostDoseChannel'.;`. What is that `resPostDoseChannel` and who sends and subscribes to this one?

Comment: You should always add the complete stack trace for questions like this.

Comment: The JSON question deserves its own separate SO thread.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: As @ArtemBilan said; the issue is `resPostDoseChannel` for which you don't show any configuration.

Comment: @ArtemBilan i have changed the stack trace. Same error i am getting for other POST also. by mistaken i have put that one earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see you have a `<int:service-activator` with an `output-channel="resPostMedChannel"`. Is there something else in your config where this one is used as an `input-channel`? Otherwise this `DirectChannel` is indeed going to fail with the mentioned *Dispatcher has no subscribers* exception.

**UPDATE**

If you are going to get a reply from that `<int:service-activator ref="medicineServiceActivator">` as a response for that upstream HTTP request, you should consider to remove that `output-channel="resPostMedChannel"` altogether. In this case the result of your service is sent into the `replyChannel` header populated by the gateway during HTTP request process: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-endpoints-service-activator

> That reply message is sent to the output channel. If no output channel has been configured, the reply is sent to the channel specified in the message’s "return address", if available.

Comment: Yes i have not used output-channel="resPostMedChannel" as input-channel. I was following this article.
https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-integration/use-spring-integration-http-inbound-spring-boot
It means i have to use it as Input-channel. but if i  want after Service activation it should return back the response. In that case how i can achieve that. Or is there a way to provide it as input-channel for something than return.?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Can we use one input channel for 2 different service activator.? Actually I am trying to fetch all data from 2 different table. and 1 have one gateway. Please suggest.

Comment: Please, raise a new SO question