# MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers bad message cause = null

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq, message-queue

I'm implementing an MQ producer which will send messages via an OUT Queue. I have the channel, bridge, outbound bean, and the JMS outbound-channel-adapter setup. When I run my test case by sending the message, I see this error-> `bad message cause=org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribersbad message cause=null`

Message config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoing="utf-8"?>
      <beans
        
      <int:channel id="inbound.rawjms">
         <int: interceptors>
            <int ref bean="jmsTransportHeaderEnricher"/>
         </int: interceptors>
      </int:channel>
    
    <int:bridge input-channel="inbound.rawjms" output-channel="inbound.endpoint"/>

<channel id="inbound.endpoint">
    <dispatcher task-executor="preDatabaseChannelExecutor"/>
</channel>

<bridge input-channel="inbound.endpoint" output-channel="inbound.endpoint.xml"/>

<channel id="inbound.endpoint.xml" datatype="java.lang.String"/>
<chain input-channel="inbound.endpoint.xml" output-channel="inbound.xml.database">
</chain>


<channel id="inbound.xml.database">
    <dispatcher task-executor="postDatabaseChannelExecutor"/>
</channel>
            
    <bean id="jms.queue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
      <constructir-arg index="0" value="${txbus.mq.destination.outbound.queue}"/>
    </bean>
    
<channel id="outbound.f.queue" datatype="java.lang.String"/>

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
           id="jms.outbound.adapter.queue"
           channel="outbound.f.queue"
           connection-factory="connectionFactory"
           destination="jms.queue"
           auto-startup="true"/>
    </beans>
```

Config Class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/message-config.xml")
public class Config{


   @Bean
   public Queue focusIn(@Value("${txbus.mq.destination}") String destinationIn){
     return new MQQueue(destinationIn);
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** I have removed the `xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schema location` from the `.xml` file as I couldn't copy them over.

Comment: You don’t show what is subscribed to that `inbound.endpoint` channel . The stack trace should really say what channel is without subscribers. Or you use very old out of support Spring Integration version…

Comment: I have added the subscriptions to `inbound.endpoint`. Could you once advise now ?

Comment: The `<chain>` cannot be empty. You also don’t show who is subscribing to that `inbound.xml.database`. See the stack trace carefully to determine what channel consumer is missing

Comment: Updated the dispatcher for the channel Ids now and also added the chain `<chain input-channel="inbound.endpoint.xml"`

Comment: Not sure what you mean: I have already commented your edit.

Comment: I mean - while you were commenting I added the following details. `<chain>` was added too and also the `<channel id>`.

Comment: `<channel id="inbound.endpoint">
    <dispatcher task-executor="preDatabaseChannelExecutor"/>
</channel>`
`<bridge input-channel="inbound.endpoint" output-channel="inbound.endpoint.xml"/>`
`<channel id="inbound.endpoint.xml" datatype="java.lang.String"/>`
`<chain input-channel="inbound.endpoint.xml" output-channel="inbound.xml.database">
</chain>`

`<channel id="inbound.xml.database">
    <dispatcher task-executor="postDatabaseChannelExecutor"/>
</channel>`

Comment: Right. I commented exactly that. Does it work now? Do you see any clues in the stack trace what part of your flow fails?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ArtemBilan. I printed the exception stack trace to figure out the channel and the suggestions above and in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597318/spring-integration-dispatcher-has-no-subscribers have helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**

Looks like I missed adding the `<service-activator> input-channel` for the "channel" which had an issue with "dispatcher has no subscribers".

I had my channel in the output-channel

The channel was `outbound.f.queue` and added the line

`<service-activator> input-channel="outbound_f.queue" ref="outboundPublisher"/>`

This link also has helped: [Spring Integration - Dispatcher has no subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597318/spring-integration-dispatcher-has-no-subscribers)

Comment: But you have that JMS outbound channel adapter for that channel, which doesn’t look like is stopped from the beginning

Comment: Note: `outbound.f.queue` is not `outbound_f.queue`. Please, be sure that quality of your questions is really the one expected here by community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask